# XSLT and assign variable to table td

Tags: xslt

```
<xsl:variable name="calculateHours" select="number(concat(substring-before(ToTime, ':'), '')) - number(concat(substring-before(FromTime, ':'), ''))"/>
    <xsl:if test="concat(substring-before(FromTime, ':'), ':00') = $Hour">
        <td align="center" valign="top" class="classCell" rowspan="$calculateHours">
            sad
        </td>
    </xsl:if>
```

but how can I use now `$calculateHours` in

```
<td align="center" valign="top" class="classCell" rowspan="$calculateHours">
```

`$calculateHours` is not transformed to number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try surround it with { } brackets, i.e. `<td align="center" valign="top" class="classCell" rowspan="{$calculateHours}">`.

Comment: @mbrc the concept you need to search for in the documentation is called "attribute value templates".